# iOS 4.2 does not allow MKMapView initialized in another thread

Tags: iphone

Because of the performance issue, I try to initialize my mapview in multithread. it works perfectly in iOS4.1 or below version.. however today some users send me emails that they got problem with the map. and I got this message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '<MKMapView: 0x643cd60; frame = (2.93669e-38 4.02966e-38; 1.4013e-45 0); transform = [1.4013e-45, 4.25886e-39, 3.68263e-35, 0, -6.62662e-10, 4.35818e-38]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)> initWithFrame:: MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread.'

I have already changed my mapview initialization to the main thread.. however, do you guys know how to initialize the map in another thread with iOS 4.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only create and modify `UIView` subclasses on the main thread. This is how the frameworks is designed. If you do need to update a view from a sub-thread you can use:

```
[myView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(makeSomethingFlashyHappen:)withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] waitUntilDone:NO];
```